# How to share Google Analytics 4 cookies between two specific subdomains and not others?

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm using Google Analytics 4 via Google Tag Manager, and need to restrict the cookies that GA4 sets to two specific subdomains (`www.domain.com` and `example.domain.com`) and have those cookies be shared, so that the session identifiers are shared: that is, GA4 tracks visitors across these subdomains as the same visitors.

I can't set the cookie at the root domain level (`.domain.com`) since that would make the cookie available to other subdomains.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you care if GA sets the same cookie for the other subdomains? It's either an Analytics reason, or a data privacy one. And if it's Analytics, then you're very likely making a mistake somewhere in your chain of thought here. Please elaborate more.